# LaTeX Switch Case with Media9

Tags: pdftex, conditionals, media9

sadly I am an absolute beginner to LaTeX programming. I would like to use a switch case to display embedded YouTube Videos using the package Media9.

```
\ifcase\value{counterVideogroup1} 
    \includemedia[
        width=0.6\linewidth,
        height=0.3375\linewidth,
        activate=pageopen,
        flashvars={
        modestbranding=1 % no YT logo in control bar
        &autohide=1 % controlbar autohide
        &showinfo=0 % no title and other info before start
        &rel=0 % no related videos after end
        }
    ]{}{http://www.youtube.com/v/SHYevzF-6mM?rel=0}
\or 
    \includemedia[
        width=0.6\linewidth,
        height=0.3375\linewidth,
        activate=pageopen,
        flashvars={
        modestbranding=1 % no YT logo in control bar
        &autohide=1 % controlbar autohide
        &showinfo=0 % no title and other info before start
        &rel=0 % no related videos after end
        }
    ]{}{http://www.youtube.com/v/urhYh2cNgAs?rel=0} 
\else 
    nothing to display
\fi
```

This works quite well for the counter value 0 but I don't really know how to manipulate the counter to display the other code for the video. I tried to use links but that generates an error message that the file was not found, probably because run indicates a program start.

```
\href{run:\setcounter{counterVideogroup1}{0}}{Video1}
```

However I think it would look better if I would use push buttons, but I don't know how to parse my code to set the counter here. I hope you can help me out.

In the end I wasn't able to test whether the code will compile at runtime. So if you see any problems with the switch case here please tell me, too.

Thanks for your time!